# MFC and dynamic linking

Tags: visual-studio-2008, dynamic, mfc, linker, freeze

I am stuck with a MFC problem.

I have read a lot about linking, static vs dynamic, and the differences between them.

My project is an open source project, with approx 2000 files which I haven't written, I have just tweaked the project.

My problem now is that I want to be able to clone the program to another computer.
The first computer can run the program, I assume this is possible since VS 2008 proffesional is installed which means that all DLL's are present. On the second computer, the program starts but freezes, I do assume that this means that it can't find a DLL or perhaps a wrong version.

I have tried static linking, but since the project contains a lof of _AFXDLL code it is impossible to compile. I have used depends.exe to generate a dependency report, parsed the report and checked if all files exists. On both computer all DLL-files are present.

My question is, is there anyway of knowing why my program freezes? Installing VS on a machine seemed to do the trick, so I assume VS pro copies some important files that I am not aware of. If so, is there a nice way of finding those files?

Comment: Freez in the sence stop working or ?? And have you used LoadLibrary?? i am not wrong your are deal with dynamic linking..

Comment: The arrow turns into the sandglass. I have searched the other computer and probably I havent redistributed the correct version of the DLL's. Found a link to which dll's to redistribute  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kche8ah(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is now solved!

The answer was simple, the CRT- and MFC-files had different versions. To make sure that the versions are always the same, one can redistribute the files along with the application. Jochen Kalmbach wrote a very simple and precise tutorial on how to do that [here](http://blog.kalmbach-software.de/2008/05/03/howto-deploy-vc2008-apps-without-installing-vcredist_x86exe/).

I hope this answer helps someone else! :)